# can i solo mine with minepeon?

Tags: solo-mining, bfgminer

i'm solo mining but it just doesnt feel right that i don't get any accepts while solo mining.

is this right? (see picture below; the top pool with the blacked out adress)

[image: minepeon screenshot]

settings:

bfgminer options: -S all
 -c /opt/minepeon/etc/miner.conf
 --no-longpoll
 --coinbase-addr 1NCWZT4hbfPw5LMpPsPauXYdVB9LYKrZM7
 --icarus-options 115200:1:1
 --icarus-timing 3.0=100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While solo-mining the miner falls back to attempting to create real-difficulty shares, a.k.a. blocks. Hence you won't see a share until you actually find a block. The only reason that pools use lower difficulty shares is in order to determine which miners are actively attempting to mine a block. Since you are the only miner there is no need to keep tabs on the miner, it's already clear who's going to get the reward.

tl;dr: this is perfectly fine, as long as the miner is showing a hashrate you'll find a block eventually, although with your current hashrate it'll take [193 years in expectation](http://www.alloscomp.com/bitcoin/calculator/json?hashrate=1000000000) for you to find a block.

Comment: thanks :) 193 years expected. but the change that i find an block the first minute is there. super tiny, but it's there! :) i'm glad to hear that my mining time didn't go to waste.

Comment: There's always luck involved in this, so it might just work out for you :-)